# What location.hash.match return if there is no hash?

Tags: javascript, html

please can you tell me what does location.hash.match return if there is no hash ?

My code :

```
function getHashValue(key) {
    return location.hash.match(new RegExp(key + '=([^&]*)'))[1];
}
test = getHashValue('test');

if (test == 'abc') {
    //code WORKS
}   
else if (test == 'sal') {
    //code WORKS
}     
else if (test == "") {
    //code DOESNT WORKS
}
```

but It doesn't works

**I forget to mentionned that my code 'getHashValue' return the value of the hash Exemple : #test=abc**

sorry I forget to mentionned it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just?

```
test = getHashValue('test');
if (test === undefined) {
  //code
}
```

### EDIT

The error was from a null return in the *match()* call.  The following change will return an empty string if the match is "" or null.

```
function getHashValue(key) {
    var match = location.hash  .match(new RegExp(key + '=([^&]*)'));
    return match ? match[1] : "";
}
```

Comment: doesn't works, look again my post, I ve edit an important Information at bottom

Comment: I see on Firefox that an exception i raised if it can't find the hash OR the hash is not assigned a value.  You need a null check.  See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `location.hash` in your browser console on any website where you're not using a hash, [you'll find that it returns the empty string `""`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location).

As such, a regex match on that will find 0 results, returning `null`, at which point, you try to access `null[1]`...

Answer (score 0):

`location.hash` will be empty string and your function:

```
function getHashValue(key) {
  return location.hash.match(new RegExp(key + '=([^&]*)'))[1];
}
```

Will indeed return `undefined`. The problem is that you are checking "undefined" value incorrectly. Change your code to:

```
test = getHashValue('test');
if (typeof(test) === 'undefined') {
  //code
}
```

Comment: I didn't know `typeof` could be used as a function. I've only ever used it `typeof operand`.

Comment: it doesn't works (I 've edited my post). I 've tried your code, but it doesn't works, sorry

Comment: @Jivings... that's just my old bad habit :) it will essentially be `typeof (a)`.
@user2372006 `test == ""` is not the same as `typeof test == "undefined"`

Comment: Doesn't works, look my post again Ive add an important information at the bottom